# Setting a list as a dictionary value results in TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, xlsx

I'm trying to convert a .xlsx file to a json file via a python script.

```py
output['operators'] = {}

for y in range(marks[0][0]+1, marks[1][0]-2):
    ops = [CTUs.get(o,o) for o in workbook.cell_value(y,2).split('/')]

    for op in ops:
        if not op in list(output['operators']):
            output['operators'][op] = {
                'name':op,
                'guns':[]
            }

        name = workbook.cell_value(y,2)
        output['operators'][op]['guns'].append(name if name != 417 else '417') #Dry this code later
```

On the 10th line (`'guns':[]`), there is a type error: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`. I don't know why and AFAIK, the keys are the only parts that need to be hashed.

Comment: What is `op` type ? seems that it is a list

Comment: Also, maybe its easier to use pandas to parse xlsx files and convert them to json

Comment: @kleerofski I'm not really doing anything with the data though. I'm just more of transferring the data to a different format than doing anything substantial with it.

Comment: @azro thats actually it. `CTUs` references a dictionary with lists as it's values.

Comment: So now you *know why*, as type list is unhashable you can't use it as a key, you can do `tuple(op)` instead, but are you you need to use a list as key ?